# JDBC sql server: set IDENTITY_INSERT ON: no effect

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, identity-insert

JDBC sql server: set IDENTITY_INSERT ON: no effect.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_FOO ON");
stmt.execute();
stmt.close();


PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into Table_FOO (id, name) values (100, 'abc')");
stmt2.execute();
stmt2.close();
```

Error: still complain that DENTITY_INSERT is OFF.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_FOO' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 0):

You could try combining the statements into 1 string and terminate statements with semicolon(s)

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_FOO ON; " +
                                                     "insert into Table_FOO (id, name) values (100, 'abc');" +
                                                     "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_FOO OFF;");
stmt.execute();
stmt.close();
```

Comment: I will try this. Do not know why the two statements not working. Thanks.

Comment: @Sunnyday, the driver executes prepared statements using `sp_executesql` so the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` goes out of scope after the statement is executed, reverting to `OFF`. The best approach, IMHO, is to include all in the same batch like SteveC suggested. An alternative is to use `Statement` instead of `PrepartedStatement` for `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;`. That will execute the query as an ad-hoc batch and avoid the error because the subsequent `PreparedStatement` is in the inner scope.